# sql server login windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to sql server express and i installed sql server express 2008 R2 with windows authentication as an administrator of the machine.

My objective is to create a database, run some scripts to create tables and data and connect to this database from an asp application.

I created a new database abc with owner as default.
I create a new login and lets call it bob with sql server authentication.(am i doing it right?) Here i chose default database for that login as abc
THen i created a new user (same name bob) within the folder of my database and mapped to the existing login bob.

Is what i am doing right???

when i try to connect through sql server management studio with sql server authentication and entered the username and password for the user bob, i get an error saying that i cant connect. 
please clarify what steps i am missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, your server uses Windows authentification, but you are trying to connect using SQL Server autentification.
If you need to connect using SQL Server authentication, you need to turn it on. In SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), select this instance, select Properties, and then on Security tab check the "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode".
After that you need to restart the SQL Server service (using SSMS or Services from Administrative Tools).

Comment: Yes I understand what you are saying. So instead I should be able to create a new windows account on my machine and create a login and user based on that right. There is no requirement that I need to use SQL login. My next question is whether I will have any problems connecting from a asp app if I use windows authentication.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: no, I cannot see any problems with connecting of asp application using windows authentication. You just need to create the login in SQL server for windows account that is used to run your ASP service. Next you need to give the appropriate rights on your database to this login.

Comment: what rights would that be?? if i assign db_owner to that database, is that sufficient?

Comment: dbo is the maximal level of user rigths. In this case you application can do ANYTHING with database. Read this SO question and answers about users and roles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395278/best-practice-on-users-roles-on-sql-server-for-a-web-application , it is very useful for you.