# EF Code first after deployment throws ProviderIncompatibleException

Tags: sql-server, iis, entity-framework-5

I have a simple EF 5.0 / Code First application developed in VS2012. In development it uses SQL Server CE. However, when I deployed it on a test server, I am getting the following stack of errors:

```
ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. 
This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string.
Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string

SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'MYDOMAIN\MYSERVER$'
```

IIS and the database are on the same server (MYSERVER). It's running Win2012, (with IIS 8 and .NET 4.5) and SQL Server 2012.

There are two things in web.config that caught my attention. First, connection string. I generated it from IIS UI; and I used my old connection strings that had "Data Source", rather than server. I used localhost and server name. I created a db user. I read somewhere that the database doesn't exist - so I deleted it. I gave permissions to NT AUTHORITY\NT SERVICE in the database. I probably did some other permutations - but the result is always the same.

The second place was Connection Factory under entity framework section. Apparently, it wasn't changed by Web Deploy; type was still SqlCeConnectionFactory, and parameter was System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0. I saw somewhere that SQL Server was the default - so I deleted it; and when that didn't work, I changed the values to SqlConnectionFactory and System.Data.SqlServer correspondingly - but again, result is the same.

By now I ran out of ideas... Given that I have a problem even when I am reading the data from existing database - I am missing something simple...

Comment: Show your config file (mostly around connection string). Are you using codefirst? If you you are not using codefirst show the first line of your SSDL.

Comment: @Pawel, thank you for your eagerness to help. My first sentence says I have a simple EF 5.0 / **Code First** application. I also tried to explain that I have a dozen permutations of first connection string, and two permutation of Connection Factory... Example: <add connectionString="Server=srvname;Database=mydb;Integrated Security=true" name="MyappContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
Again, this is just one of many examples. I hope, it will help somebody to solve my original problem

Comment: Do you have the stack trace? I am wondering when it happens. Also are you sure that the user 'MYDOMAIN\MYSERVER$' is the right user that has rights to connect to the database?

Comment: I put the stack trace on http://www.rabinovich.org/.nero/StackTrace.html (MYDOMAIN and MYSERVER are *not* the real names). This message comes when I am using Windows authentication. For troubleshooting I created such user in the database. Among other things, I tried database login and created such user in the database. Connection string does have User Name=blah;Password=blahblah instead of Integrated Security (as I expect). My old EF4 code connects to the same database without any problems with similar connection string (it has Data Source instead of Server, which I also tried)

Comment: Thanks for the stack trace. To me it looks like the user the web app is running as does not have permissions to login to the database.

Comment: To me it looks the same way :) The question is how to fix it! While I prefer to use Windows authentication, at this time I would be happy to get *anything* work. Needless to say, I tried to login manually with DB credentials, and it works fine. The closest I found to set it up is here: http://evonet.com.au/setting-up-sql-server-2008-for-an-asp-net-website-on-iis-7-0/ So, I set up NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE in the database; even gave it dbadmin role; but the error is the same. I may be wrong, but I don't think it's permissions issue - ProviderIncompatibleException probably means what it says

Comment: I don't think it's about what user the database is running as but how to grant sufficient permissions in the database for the user the web app is running as. Try taking a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395278/best-practice-on-users-roles-on-sql-server-for-a-web-application - seems like a good starting point

Comment: Thanks, Pawel. Clearly, you are trying a different question from the one I asked. So, obviously, I wasn't able to state the question correctly. I'll try to research more.